# Grails create-controller fails (inside Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, grails, eclipse-plugin

first off: sorry if the question should not belong here.
I am fairly new to grails and wanted to set it up with eclipse (Spring Tool Suite + Grails/Groovy plugin).
But already the creation of a HelloWord controller fails with huge exeptions.
I did set JAVA_HOME and GRAILS_HOME in my environment variables in windows.

I keep it short I uploaded it to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/aesgcyP7

As you can see it fails with:

> \HelloWorldController.groovy: 1: unexpected token: package @ line 1,
> column 1.
>
> ```
>    package 7daystobuild
> ```

Background Info: I also tried newer grails versions (2.2.4, since the plugin uses 2.2.3) and both jdk 1.7 and 1.6)

Thanks

Comment: I don't think your package name is valid. I've never officially looked it up for Groovy, but I believe Groovy follows [Java naming conventions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) for packages, which states you can't have package names start with a digit.

Comment: @user2264997 you're correct - change your comment to an answer so you get proper credit

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your package name is valid. I've never officially looked it up for Groovy, but I believe Groovy follows [Java naming conventions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) for packages, which states you can't have package names start with a digit.

Comment: *All things being equal, the simplest solution tends to be the right one...*. Best example [here](http://fridayreflections.typepad.com/.shared/image.html?/photos/uncategorized/2007/10/16/toon15.jpg). :)